# Multiple inheritance error 'invalid use of incomplete type'

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-inheritance, circular-dependency

I have a dialog window `settings` that I want to display all values from my `breadData` object, and to do so I want to have `settings` inherit `breadData`'s protected members. I try to forward declare breadData, but I'm getting a couple errors in my code.

```
/home/--/breadPull/prj/settings.h:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct breadData'
/home/--/breadPull/prj/resultwnd.h:7: error: forward declaration of 'struct breadData'
```

For one, `breadData` is not a struct, why does the compiler think breadData is a struct? Secondly I don't understand what the second line is trying to say. My only guess is because there are a lot of circular dependencies in my program. Here's the relevant code:

settings.h

```
#include <QDialog>
#include "breaddata.h"

class breadData;

namespace Ui {
class Settings;
}

class Settings : public QDialog, public breadData
{
    Q_OBJECT
    //.....
```

---

breadData.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "resultwnd.h"
#include "settings.h"


class MainWindow;
class resultWnd;

class breadData
{
public:
    breadData(std::string);
    ~breadData();
    //read in data file that provides all information
    bool readData();

    //.......
```

---

resultWnd.h

```
include <QGroupBox>
#include "breaddata.h"

class breadData;

namespace Ui {
class resultWnd;
}

class resultWnd : public QGroupBox
//.....
```

Comment: `breaddata.h` includes `settings.h` and vice versa. This is an include circular dependency and cannot work. Fortunately, there are plenty of SO questions about it.

Comment: @juanchopanza `MainWindow` and `breadData` are also circular dependencies and work. Just as long as the header file does not include any implementation

Comment: If they work they work by chance. You should remove the circular dependencies.

Comment: @juanchopanza read up on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c/628079#628079

Comment: No thanks, this is not really a problem that I ever have to deal with.

Comment: in the includes you have fwd declaration. try to remove the includes from both h files and put them in the cpp.

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency. breaddata.h includes settings.h before declaring breaddata. settings.h requires the declaration of breaddata for the inheritance.

Thus the file the preprocessor creates when compiling a file that includes breaddata first looks like this (indentation to visualize the recursive insertion of included header files):

```
<content of breaddata.h>:
    <content of vector, string, QtWidget, QMainWindow, mainwindow.h and ui_mainwindow.h>
    ...
    <content of resultWnd>:
        ...
        class breaddata; //forward declaration mentioned in the error message 
        ...
    <content of settings.h>:
        ...
        class Settings : public QDialog, public breadData //DANG!
        ...
   class breaddata { ... //too late
```

Summarized:

```
class breaddata; //forward declaration mentioned in the error message 
...
class Settings : public QDialog, public breadData //DANG!
...
class breaddata { ... //too late
```

The solution here is to avoid the includes in breaddata.h, especially settings.h. If necessary, forward-declare Settings. The rule of thumb is to include in headers only if you must, and forward-declare whenever you can.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have an incomplete understanding of the following:

1. The precompiler
2. The difference between declarations and definitions and purpose of using the former.
3. The purpose and use of `namespace`s

Without knowing more about your code than what you've shown, the following should solve your problem:

settings.h

```
#ifndef SETTINGS_H
#define SETTINGS_H

// Your code as above

#endif
```

breaddata.h

```
#ifndef BREADDATA_H
#define BREADDATA_H

// Your code as above

#endif
```

resultWnd.h

```
#ifndef RESULTWND_H
#define RESULTWND_H

// Your code as above

#endif
```

I suspect that this will not solve your problem entirely though. Based on your second error message, I suspect you have left important lines of code out of your question so nobody will be able to give you a definitive answer to solve your problem.

**I suggest you edit the code in your question to include all lines that contain the `breadData`, `Settings` and `resultWnd`**

It is possible to solve this, we just need to see how the three classes are bound together so we can help you untangle them.

---

---

The reason the compiler thinks you're using a `struct` is purely historical. The `class` keyword was introduced in C++ with the intention to replace the `struct`. Previously, in C, only the `struct` keyword exists. As far as I know, the only difference between `struct`s and `class`es is the default access level. `class`es default to `private` while `struct`s default to `public`. Otherwise, they have identical usage.